# Only Need to write Junit for Integer.valueOf() in Java

Tags: java, junit, integer

So here is the thing, I found  new Integer() in my code and which is deprecated now I planed to remove that pic of code (new Integer()) to Integer.valueOf() but as company rules I have to write the Junit for that change, I just need to verify that pic of code no need to write whole coverage of the method, Now I am getting confused, how I can do it.

Before:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public List getLogsByLcrErrorCodeInLast(String code, long period) throws Exception {
        Object params = new ObjectPair(new Integer(code), new MesDbUtil(ibatis).getPastMesDbDate(period));
        List mesdbLogs = client.queryForList("LcrLog.getLogsByLcrErrorCodeInLast", params);
        Iterator mesdbLogsIter = mesdbLogs.iterator();
        List results = new ArrayList();
        while (mesdbLogsIter.hasNext()) {
            MesDbLcrLog mesdbLog = (MesDbLcrLog) mesdbLogsIter.next();
            results.add(mesdbLog.getLog());
        }
        return results;
    }
```

After::

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public List getLogsByLcrErrorCodeInLast(String code, long period) throws Exception {
        Object params = new ObjectPair(Integer.valueOf(code), new MesDbUtil(ibatis).getPastMesDbDate(period));
        List mesdbLogs = client.queryForList("LcrLog.getLogsByLcrErrorCodeInLast", params);
        Iterator mesdbLogsIter = mesdbLogs.iterator();
        List results = new ArrayList();
        while (mesdbLogsIter.hasNext()) {
            MesDbLcrLog mesdbLog = (MesDbLcrLog) mesdbLogsIter.next();
            results.add(mesdbLog.getLog());
        }
        return results;
    }
```

I tried to do like following, I don't know is it correct or not, and need to go for some professional way for it too because of code review;

```
public class integerValueOf(){
    private Integer code=23;
    @Test
        public void testGetLogsByLcrErrorCodeInlast() throws Exception{
            assertEquals(new Integer(code), Integer.valueOf(code));
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no change of functionality there. What exactly are you trying to test that wasn't tested before?

Comment: Just want to make sure that Integer.valueOf() is fine over there and for that need to write Junit. They said no need functional Junit just verify that particular changed code with Junit thats all. But I don't know how I can accomplish it, I tried like above but don't know its going to work or not.

Comment: I think @Stultuske is right, why do you want a new test? Your method has no changes that would require a new test.

Comment: @PradipLamsal if it isn't fine after the change, either your existing tests run as they should, or, if there's a difference, your existing tests are no good.

Answer (score 2):

Are you unit testing every other API in the JRE? No? Why would you unit test Integer.valueOf(...) then?

Your existing unit tests for `getLogsByLcrErrorCodeInLast` should cover the change in the integer instantiation. E.g. you have tests for different values of `code` and check that you get the expected `params` in `client.queryForList(...)`.

If you don't have the tests, then you need to write them before you change the code.

Edit: I didn't even notice it earlier, but your production code converts a String to an Integer and your sugested unit test converts an Integer to an Integer. You're idea is fundamentally flawed because it doesn't test the code that you execute in production. It lets errors like this pass testing with green flags.

Comment: That is exactly it, if your test for `getLogsByLcrErrorCodeInLast` is properly written, it does not care about how the `uut` creates its integers internally. By running the test once before the change and after the change you have verified the change does not break the code, done.

Comment: @Torben I know that thing but they need that just write the Junit for that particular method only with @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") HERE IS EXAMPLE WHAT OTHER ARE DOING ::

Comment: @Test
 public void getLogByRecId() {
  //int hashmap Test was new Integer(int)
        assertEquals(oldWay.get("new Integer(integerPrimitive)"),newWay.get("integerPrimitive") );

 }

Comment: @PradipLamsal You asked for a professional way. That is not a professional way. You can either trust a stranger from the internet or insist on doing it your way. That's it. :)